# How do I automatically refresh a page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

If pc1 and pc2 on the same page. Pc1 change the status on a field, how do I get pc2's aspx page to get the update without a refresh?

Comment: Ajax, Websockets, cmon..

Comment: You could use ajax for this. However, your question is to vague to provide a good answer. You'll need to post a more specific question after you have tried to implement something.

Comment: Use Websockets to push updates to the client, or use AJAX to poll for updates from the client.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you need more power.

You can use the [ajax push engine](http://www.ape-project.org/). It's nice because both the server side and client side code are written in JavaScript.

Flash can do that kind of stuff, if you like Flash. But I'm not sure how.